# Closed form matrix derivative of $\operatorname{tr}(A\exp(X))$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus, matrix-exponential, scalar-fields

I am interested in finding a closed form expression for the following matrix derivative:

> $\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{X}}\operatorname{Tr}\left(\mathbf{A}\exp(\mathbf{X})\right)$

Where we assume that $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{X}$ are both symmetric $n\times n$ matrices. By applying the following identity:

> $\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{X}} \operatorname{Tr}\left(\mathbf{A} \mathbf{X}^{k}\right)=\sum_{r=0}^{k-1}\left(\mathbf{X}^{r} \mathbf{A} \mathbf{X}^{k-r-1}\right)^{T}$(found in https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf)

I figured one can use the definition of a matrix exponential to obtain the following expression:

> $\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{X}}\operatorname{Tr}\left(\mathbf{A}\exp(\mathbf{X})\right)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{X}} \operatorname{Tr}\left(\frac{1}{k!}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{X}^{k}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum_{r=0}^{k-1}\left(\mathbf{X}^{r} \mathbf{A} \mathbf{X}^{k-r-1}\right)^{T}$

Where we skip over $k=0$ since $\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{X}}\operatorname{Tr}\left(\mathbf{A})\right)=\mathbf{O}$.

I am not sure if this expression can be reduced to something which is in closed form. If you are able to suggest a method with which this might be possible, or a different method entirely, I would be helped greatly.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions and help.

Comment: We can get an answer from the formula given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_of_the_exponential_map)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\BR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\bR#1{\big(#1\big)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\op{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\b{\beta} \def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\p{\partial}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
$Since $X$ is a real symmetric matrix, it can be *diagonalized* as follows
$$\eqalign{
X &= QBQ^T, \qquad Q^TQ=I,\quad B=\Diag{\b_k},\\
}$$
Given a real differentiable function (and its derivative)
$$f(z), \qquad f'(z) = \frac{df}{dz}$$
when this function is applied to a matrix argument,
the $\sf Daleckii\:Krein\,$ theorem tells us
$$\eqalign{
F &= f(X) \\
dF &= Q\BR{R\odot\LR{Q^TdX\:Q}}Q^T \\
R_{jk} &= \begin{cases}
{\large\frac{f(\b_j)-f(\b_k)}{\b_j-\b_k}} \quad\quad {\rm if}\;\b_j\ne\b_k \\
\\
\quad f'(\b_k) \qquad\quad {\rm otherwise} \\
\end{cases}
\\
}$$
where ${\odot}$ denotes the elementwise/Hadamard product.

In this particular problem, we conveniently have
$${f'(z) = f(z) = \exp(z)}$$
Let's also introduce the Frobenius product, which is a handy
notation for the trace
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \|A\|^2_F \qquad \{ {\rm Frobenius\;norm} \} \\
}$$
This is also called the double-dot or double contraction product.

When applied to vectors $(n=\o)$ it reduces to the standard dot product.

The properties of the underlying trace function allow the terms in a
Frobenius product to be rearranged in many useful ways, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= B:A \\
A:B &= A^T:B^T \\
C:\LR{AB} &= \LR{CB^T}:A &= \LR{A^TC}:B \\
}$$

The Frobenius and Hadamard products commute in the following sense
$$\eqalign{
A:\LR{B\odot C}
  = \LR{A\odot B}:C 
\;=\; \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij}C_{ij} \\\\
}$$

---

Use the above notation to rewrite the objective function
and calculate its gradient.
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= A:F \\
d\phi &= A:dF \\
 &= A : Q\BR{R\odot\LR{Q^TdX\:Q}}Q^T \\
 &= Q\BR{R\odot\LR{Q^TAQ}}Q^T : dX \\
\grad{\phi}{X}
 &= Q\BR{R\odot\LR{Q^TAQ}}Q^T \\
}$$